# Liferay Page redirection

Tags: java, redirect, liferay, liferay-6

I have developed a theme in liferay 6.1. I have a page named "localhost:8080/home" but now i want that on clicking this link of the page, it should be redirected to localhost:8080

Any suggestions are welcomed. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please go through the Lifeary documentation for theme and understand its usage. This question does not clarify what you are doing.

Also, why the `friendly-url` tag??

Comment: I just want to redirect a page to other page and if thats possible then do guide me. And for the friendly-url tag i thought may be it is possible to solve my problem using it.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Themes I suppose, so please update the question accordingly. or if it is related then do you want to redirect using themes (that is absurd but still possible :-) )?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused a little bit, so just some things you should know:

1. You can't (normally and without hacks) have a page named "localhost:8080". Every Page (or 'Layout' in Liferay) has a short name, that takes it's part of the url. This is often called "friendly url" but it's often confused with the "friendly url feature", which is a way to shorten your url request data.
   So you're always going to have urls like 'localhost:8080/something'. The same holds for the 'home' page
2. You can partially shorten the Url by using 'virtual host'. It removes the part of the url before your page's name (like removing the web/guest or user/username ) suffix
3. You can use the 'friendly url' feature to shorten the part of the url that goes after the page's name, and contains request information like lifecycle state info or custom request parameters